# Power series uniqueness

Tags: analysis, power-series

I'm having trouble with a problem for my thesis. I have two analytical functions which to first order are different, does it mean that they are different functions? Remember they have a series expansion..

Comment: Yes: If they disagree at first order, their first derivatives are different, and so they are different functions. Alternatively, the expansion of their difference has a nonzero first-order term, whereas the zero function does not.

Comment: And the same for the 0-th order, right? Nice explanation actually.

Comment: The functions disagree at zeroth order iff their values at the base point are different.